# How to know whether a Realm object was successfully updated?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using Realm mobile database. I update Realm objects using the following code. I want to get a callback with whether or not that Realm object was successfully updated.

```
do {
    let realm = try Realm()
    realm.beginWrite()
    if let Settings = realm.objects(ModelClass).first {
        Settings.settingsVal = settingsValue
        realm.add(Settings, update: true)
    }
    try realm.commitWrite()
}
catch {

}
```

Comment: stick a log statement inside the try block?

Comment: can you specify via code?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to achieve what you are looking to do, including using closures/delegates to provide a callback mechanism, however the simplest way to know that the update was successful would be to add code inside the `try` block:

```
do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        realm.beginWrite()
        if let Settings = realm.objects(ModelClass).first {
            Settings.settingsVal = settingsValue
            realm.add(Settings, update: true)
        }
        try realm.commitWrite()
            print("Success")
        }
        catch{

        }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible via 'addNotificationBlock'?